# How do I check the value of a non-existent variable without crashing the program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JSON output from an HTTP get.
I am then using JSON.parse from nodejs.

The output is basically like this:

```
items: [
    snippet: {
        foo: "bar",
        bar: "foo
    }
    snippet: {
        foo: "bar",
        bar: "foo
    }
    snippet: {
        foo: "bar",
        bar: "foo
    }
]
```

My code is then as such:

```
foo1 = items[0].snippet.foo
bar1 = items[0].snippet.bar
```

this variable declaration all works fine, until I get to the variables that might not exist sometimes.

```
foo4 = items[4].snippet.foo
```

Of course, this right here does not exist. I thought that I would be able to simply do an if(foo4 == 'Null') then set foo4 = 'not existing' so it does not crash my program later. However, the program crashes when DECLARING this variable itself... how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Your object is not valid because keys are not unique. Is it `items: [...]` instead? Then you can check the length of the array before indexing it. In the lines of `L = items.length()` then `items[i].snippet.foo` where `i` is between `0` and `L` (e.g. in a loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ES2020 there is cool feature called [optional chaining](https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://v8.dev/features/nullish-coalescing), so you can try to combine them:

```
foo4 = items[4]?.snippet?.foo ?? 'not existing'
```

So if `items[4]` is null or undefined part `items[4]?.snippet?.foo` will set undefined to foo4  and then operator  `??` will add default value to variable foo 4

Comment: Great! I did a quick Google and found optional chaining works for Node.js 14.0.0^, however, do you happen to know if nullish coalescing will be compatible?

Comment: @RishabJain according to [docs](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) Node.js 14.0.0 is supported